# Calling R from SAS and memory issues

Tags: r, memory, sas

I am working with a very large dataset (~30 million rows).  I have typically work with this dataset in SAS but would like to use some machine learning applications that do not exist in SAS but do in R.  Unfortunately my PC can't handle a dataset of this size in R due to how R stores the entire dataset in memory.

Will calling the R functions from a SAS program solve this? At the very least I can run SAS on a server (I cannot do this with R).

Comment: No, it won't because SAS just passes the commands to R, it's not a conversion mechanism of any kind. What type of ML model are you trying to run in R?

Comment: So once you call R from SAS you have to store the dataset in memory?  I'm just using typical ML algorithms, random forest, neural nets, svm etc.

Comment: This website: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/11/25/twelve-advantages-to-calling-r-from-the-sasiml-language.html states: "In the SAS/IML Studio environment, SAS and R can run on different machines. You can run SAS on a huge server and run R on your local PC."  So I thought this was possible.  I work for a corporation where we predominantly use SAS.  As such I have access to servers where I can use SAS but I only have R on my local PC.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan SAS can work across environments and across DBs in ways that many other tools cannot. In Base, you can have specific steps run locally, others on the server and switch dynamically as needed. The code to do is pretty minimal as well.

Comment: what version of SAS are you using? Some of the newer versions ship with SAS if the IT team installed it. You need to check the server version to see if R is installed there. Or maybe you can convince IT to install it in the server? Is there anyway to split up any of the processing to have it handle less data at a time? Though I'm guessing you've already thought of that.